# How to update a dynamically generated datatable without touching the rest of the page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a setup in a view, where I display datatables dynamically. That is happening inside a p:accordion-Element, which is generating the tabs dynamically (and therefore the datatables inside).

The user now has the possibility (well, should have..) to add, edit and remove objects to the datatable and therefore to the object that is represented by the tab.

The add- and edit-functions work via dialogs. After successful adding or editing I want to update the datatable containing the data.

If I update the whole accordion-panel I lose the focus on the current tab which is really bad for the user-experience, especially because the other sub-pages of the project always only update the datatable.

After some googling I found out that I can't generate the IDs of JSF-components dynamically, what would make the whole thing a process of minutes.

I also do not have any index I could use to "cheat" and save in my backing-bean when I open the dialog.

I also found out that I could work-around this issue by using JSTL but this is prohibited due to a limited set of allowed languages.

The current setup looks like this:

```
<p:accordionPanel id="academicYearAccordionPanel"
                  value="#{academicYearAndClassController.academicYears}"
                  var="academicYear" multiple="true" dynamic="true" activeIndex="-1"
                  style="width:100%;">

    <p:tab id="academicYear-#{academicYear.academicYear}" title="Jahrgang - #{academicYear.academicYear}">
        <p:outputPanel style="float:right">
            <p:commandButton value="Löschen" icon="ui-icon-close"
                             actionListener="#{academicYearAndClassController.setAcademicYear(academicYear)}"
                             process="@this"
                             oncomplete="PF('wConfirmAcademicYearDelete').show();">
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:outputPanel>
        <p:spacer style="height:50px;" />
        <p:separator />

        <!-- Tabcontent -->
        <p:outputPanel>
            <p:outputPanel style="float:right">
                <p:commandButton value="Hinzufügen" icon="ui-icon-plusthick"
                                 actionListener="#{academicYearAndClassController.setAcademicYear(academicYear)}"
                                 process="@this"
                                 oncomplete="PF('wAddSchoolclassDialog').show();">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:outputPanel>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText
                    value="Klassen des #{academicYear.academicYear}. Jahrgangs" />
                <p:spacer style="height:50px;" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Keine Klassen vorhanden"
                         id="schoolclassTable"
                         var="schoolclass"
                         selection="#{academicYearAndClassController.schoolclass}"
                         value="#{academicYearAndClassController.getSchoolclasses(academicYear)}"
                         selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{schoolclass.name}"
                         scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500">
                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{schoolclass.identifier}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Klassenlehrkraft">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{schoolclass.teacher.name} (#{schoolclass.teacher.symbol})" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Klassenraum">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{schoolclass.room.name} (#{schoolclass.room.locationName})" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

I want to update the element with the ID `schoolclassTable`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What version of Primefaces are u using?

Comment: I am using PrimeFaces 5.0. In the meanwhile I changed the setup to a dropdown-menu for academic years and a single Datatable with classes is shown for each academic year. It works and that solves the problem for me.